# Ideal consisting of zero divisors

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $I$ be a finitely generated ideal of a commutative ring $R$. Assume every element of $I$ is a zero divisor. Does then exist a $x \neq 0$ in $R$ with $xI=0$?

This is true if $0$ is a decomposable ideal, for example if $R$ is noetherian. I wonder if we actually need this. Doesn't it sound plausible? The problem is that we cannot just multiply the elements which kill the generators of $I$, the product can vanish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, for a counterexample see Exercises 2-2-6,7 pp. 62-63 in Kaplansky: Commutative Rings (excerpted below). See also the discussion following Theorem 82 p.56.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you explain the notation? I mean what are $Z(A)$ and $<(A)$?

Comment: @Martin: $ Z(A) $ is the set of zero-divisors on the $R$-module $A$, i.e. the elements of $R$ that annihilate some nonzero element of $A$. The latter is presumably a misprint for the former.