# Ideal has zero annihilator iff it contains a non zero divisor

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring and $I\subseteq R$ an ideal.
Then $\operatorname{Ann}(I)=0$ if and only if $I$ contains a non zero divisor.

$\Leftarrow$ is trivial, if $I$ contains a non zero divisor then its annilhator must be zero.
What's trickier is $\Rightarrow$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\ann}{ann}$

The statement is true.  Here is a sketch of the proof of the nontrivial direction using standard Noetherian ring theory.

Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring.  Recall than an associated prime ideal of $R$ is a prime ideal of the form $P=\ann(x)$ for some $x\in R$.
It is well-known that the set of zero divisors of $R$ is the union of the associated prime ideals of $R$ and that any ideal consisting of zero divisors is contained in an associated prime ideal.
It follows immediately that if $I$ is an ideal of zero divisors, then $xI=0$ for some nonzero $x\in R$.

This fails if we only assume $R$ is a commutative ring and $I$ is a finitely generated ideal.
See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7361/ideal-consisting-of-zero-divisors).